# Condensing PHP query

Tags: php

I have a piece of code which I suspect could be written in a more efficient way but I'm still a little rusty on some PHP queries.

Is there a better way to write the following query:

```
<?php 
if(qtrans_getLanguage()=='en'): echo 'Latest News'; endif;
if(qtrans_getLanguage()=='it'): echo 'Ultime notizie'; endif; 
if(qtrans_getLanguage()=='de'): echo 'Aktuelle Nachrichten'; endif; 
if(qtrans_getLanguage()=='zh'): echo '最新消息'; endif;
if(qtrans_getLanguage()=='es'): echo 'Últimas noticias'; endif;
if(qtrans_getLanguage()=='fr'): echo 'Dernières nouvelles'; endif; 
?>
```

Comment: You could try a switch statement http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [lookup table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table):

```
$table = array(
   'en' => 'Latest News',
   'it' => 'Ultime notizie',
   ....
);

echo $table[qtrans_getLanguage()];
```

Comment: +1, you've typed it faster than me :) Anyway I don't get those people who downvoted my answer (now deleted) just for being 14 secs slower.

Comment: @Flavius you shouldn't have deleted, don't be scared of irrational downvoters. It would have been balanced by fair voters.

Comment: @MrCode it would have had no sense, alexn typed literally the same solution as me. But that kind of behavior (+1ing one answer and -1ing the exact same answer) shows how poisoned SO has become. For the record: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q52kFL8zVoM.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a language map. It looks like you're trying to simulate [`i18n`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization), but commonly you'll see language file definitions such as:

```
// lang.php
$LANG = array();
include_once('lang/english.php');
include_once('lang/french.php');

// lang/english.php
$LANG['en'] = array();
$lang['en']['LATEST_NEWS'] = 'Latests News';

// lang/french.php
$LANG['fr'] = array();
$lang['fr']['LATEST_NEWS'] = 'Dernières nouvelles';

// ... etc.
```

Then you can use the following within code:

```
<?= $LANG[qtrans_getLanguage()]['LATEST_NEWS']; ?>
```

---

Alternatively, you can make it *very* simple and only include the language file you need and then keep your constants to a minimum:

```
// lang/en.php
$LANG['LATEST_NEWS'] = 'Latest News';
```

Then in your header:

```
include('lang/' . qtrans_getLanguage() . '.php');

<?= $LANG['LATEST_NEWS']; ?>
```